Stripe Connect - can marketplace keep all funds until withdrawn by merchant
I'm implementing Stripe connect for a project where payments are split between the merchant and the platform (marketplace). I think I understand how to execute the split with each transaction but I'm wondering, is there a way to keep all the money in the platform's account while showing the merchant they can withdraw the funds and then only actually give them the funds if they withdraw them?
If this is possible, can you point me to the right documentation on how to implement it? Also will it need a full Strip Connect API integration or can I get away with say Stripe Express integration?

This is known as "Separate charges and transfers": https://docs.stripe.com/connect/separate-charges-and-transfers
As the platform, you can decide when to initiate the transfers to your connected accounts and how much to transfer.

Also will it need a full Strip Connect API integration or can I get
away with say Stripe Express integration?

You can transfer to Express accounts (for supported platform/connected account locations), but you will need to build a Connect integration to manage this, yes.
See the guide here using account controller properties: https://docs.stripe.com/connect/design-an-integration#select-properties
Or using legacy account types: https://docs.stripe.com/connect/accounts

Awesome! If you've done this before, how much longer would you estimate it takes to do vs just to do the default split with every transaction. 50% longer-ish?
